# Why does this code rewrite the dictionaries in a list every time a loop happens? (I end up with a list of the same dictionaries)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm creating a very simple program as a learning experience. I'm going to try to explain what I expect from the program. **First I generate 5 dictionaries, that have random values assigned to each key.**

This works just fine, I can print the created random dictionary after each loop. Now my problem is, that **I want to be able to access each one of the 5 random dictionaries later**, so I want to create a new indexed dictionary for each loop (*fox1, fox2, fox3*,...etc.) This is my attempt of the code:

```
from random import random, uniform

foxlist = list()

fox = {
    "tame": 0,
    "int": 0,
    "gen": 0,
}

txt = "Fox {}: "

for i in range(5):

    foxlist.append("fox" + format(i+1))
    foxlist[i] = {}

    for x in fox:
        att = uniform(0.0, 0.3)
        fox[x] = round(att, 2)

    foxlist[i] = fox

    print(txt.format(i+1))
    print(fox)

print(foxlist)
```

Now if you run the program, you notice that the final *foxlist* is indeed a list of dictionaries, however each item in the list is the same dictionary - it rewrites all the previous items each loop. It also doesn't include the indexed *fox1,fox2*,... **Any tips on how I could save each dictionary for a later access?**

Answer (score 1):

`fox` is a variable defined outside the loop, and so is the same object on every iteration of the loop. On each iteration, you change the value of some fields in `fox`, but always in that same object.

To resolve this, make a different object on each iteration, perhaps by copying a single initial object.

Also, `foxlist.append("fox" + format(i+1))` and `foxlist[i] = {}` have no effect and should be removed. In each of these, the value in the list is immediately overwritten.

```
...
foxbase = {
    "tame": 0,
    "int": 0,
    "gen": 0,
}
...
for i in range(5):
    fox=dict(foxbase)
    foxlist.append("fox" + format(i+1)) # This has no effect, delete
    ... 
    foxlist[i] = {}  # This has no effect, delete
    ...
    foxlist[i] = fox
    ...
```

Comment: And if you want to, you can do it in a oneliner: `foxlist = [{f"Fox{i+1}":{k:round(uniform(0.0, 0.3),2) for k in fox}} for i in range(5)]`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answers, a very nice explanation for a beginner :)